# Link in navbar using dynamic popup, framework7

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

Im using a "Fixed" style layout page with a navbar in my main-page which I also would like to use in a popup. In my main page it all works well and I can use links/icons in the navbar to trigger certain events. However, when copying the same structure to a popup I cant get any events triggered.

In my main page where all is working the HTML:

```
<div class="views">
  <div class="view view-main">
    <div class="pages">
      <div data-page="index" class="page navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">
    <!-- Top Navbar-->
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
       <div class="center">Hello</div>
        <div class="right">
          <a href="" class="navbarIcon">
           <i class="f7-icons">add_round</i>
          </a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    <!-- /End of Top Navbar-->

    <div class="page-content" >
      <div class="content-block">
      ...
```

I can use below JS to trigger an event based on a click:

```
$$('.navbarIcon').on('click', function (e) {
console.log("Hello");
});
```

When using the same structure for a dynamic popup I cant get any events triggered. The popup HTML is:

```
    var popupHTML =
    '<div class="popup popup-stats">'+
    '<div class="view view-popup">' +
    '<div class="pages">' +
    '<div data-page="popup-stats" class="page navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">' +

    '<div class="navbar">' + 
    '<div class="navbar-inner">' +
    '<div class="center">Hello</div>' +
    '<div class="right">' +
    '<a href="" class="navbarIcon">' +
    '<i class="f7-icons">add_round</i>' +
    '</a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="page-content">' +
    '<div class="content-block">'+
    ...
    myApp.popup(popupHTML);
```

I would expect that the same JS code gets triggered by having this navbar in the popup but nothing happens. I can see in the console that the class navbarIcon indeed gets active but still nothing triggers the JS code. When I add a "close-popup" to the class the popup does close but nothing else

I tried catching the close/closing of the popup but this also leads to no response in the JS. I tried this with:

```
$$('.popup-stats').on('popup:opened', function () {
console.log('About Popup opened') 
});
$$('.popup-stats').on('popup:close', function () {
console.log('About Popup is closing')
});
$$('.popup-stats').on('popup:open', function () {
console.log('Services Popup is opening')
});
$$('.popup-stats').on('popup:closed', function () {
console.log('Services Popup is closed')
});
$$('.close-popup').on('click', function () {
console.log('Services Popup is closed')
});
```

Any idea as to how I can fix this so I can catch the popup closing and using the links in the navbar?

I can also add that I tried switching from a dynamic popup to a dynamic page with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the new elements are loaded dynamically, it is expected that you use this way to listen to events:

```
$$(document).on('popup:closed', '.popup-stats', function () {
    console.log('Services Popup is closed');
});
```

Also do not forget to include the codes inside the onPageInit function of your current page that has the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, part of the answer is found! I added my event listeners BEFORE the popup in DOM. So, now I can trigger the JS:

```
$$('.close-popup').on('click', function () {
console.log('Services Popup is closed')
});
```

and

```
$$('.navbarIcon').on('click', function (e) {
console.log("Hello");
});
```

By placing it directly after the `myApp.popup(popupHTML);`

However, I have not been able to trigger the `'popup:close'` and `'popup:closed'` events.

Any ideas?